# C# Select from GroupOdd and insert into others table with conditions

Tags: c#, sql

Example data:

GroupOdd table

```
Teacher_Name  Standard  Subject  Weekly_Slot  Balance_Slot  Sum_Weekly_Slot
A             Y1        MZ       1            1             3 
A             Y2        BC       1            1             3
A             Y3        BM       1            1             3
B             Y1        MT       1            1             2 
B             Y2        BI       1            1             2
C             Y3        PJ       1            1             1
.
.
.
```

Then there is 9 groups (`Group_Odd_1` until `Group_Odd_9`).
Each groups consists of `Teacher_Name`, `Standard`, `Subject` column. Because I want each group don't have duplicate `Standard` and `Teacher_Name` and `balance_slot` means how many times it can be slot into the groups.

Sample data:
Group_Odd_1

```
Teacher_Name  Standard  Subject
A             Y1        MZ
B             Y2        BI
C             Y3        PJ
```

so therefore I try following to get `Teacher_Name, Standard, Subject, Balance_Slot FROM GroupOdd order by Sum_Weekly_Slot` and insert it into 9 groups (`Group_Odd_1` until `Group_Odd_9`).

- However, if the `Balance_Slot = 0`, then skip and continue with next row.
- If the `Teacher_Name` or `Standard` exist in the `Group_Odd_1`, then continue check with `Group_Odd_2` until `Group_Odd_9`.
- If still exist, then skip and continue next row.
- If `Teacher_Name` or `Standard` not exist (example not exist in `Group_Odd_9`), update `Teacher_Name`, `Standard`, `Subject` into the `Group_Odd_9` and minus 1 for `Balance_Slot` in `GroupOdd WHERE Teacher_Name AND Standard AND Subject`.
- Then continue with next row.

I tried following but encountered error. I am correcting the coding following, so still thinking better coding for above scenario. So appreciate if you can advice me the right coding. Thanks.

```
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Teacher_Name, Standard, Subject, Balance_Slot FROM GroupOdd order by sum_weekly_slot desc";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            int BalanceSlot = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Balance_Slot"].ToString());

            if (BalanceSlot > 0)
            {

                for (int j = 1; j <= 9;)
                {
                    //bool TeacherNameExist = true;
                    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                    cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM group_odd_" + j + " WHERE (Teacher_Name = @Teacher_Name OR Standard = @Standard OR Subject = @Subject)";
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher_Name", dr["Teacher_Name"].ToString());
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Standard", dr["Standard"].ToString());
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", dr["Subject"].ToString());
                    SQLiteDataAdapter da2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd2);
                    da2.Fill(dt2);
                    if (dt2.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        int BSlot = BalanceSlot - 1;
                        //cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO group_odd_" + j + " (Teacher_Name, Standard, Subject) VALUES (@Teacher_Name, @Standard, @Subject)";
                        cmd2.CommandText = "Update group_odd_" + j + " SET Teacher_Name = @Teacher_Name, Standard = @Standard, Subject = @Subject";
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher_Name", dr["Teacher_Name"].ToString());
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Standard", dr["Standard"].ToString());
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", dr["Subject"].ToString());
                        cmd2.CommandText = "Update GroupOdd set Balance_Slot = @Balance_Slot WHERE Teacher_Name = @Teacher_Name AND Standard = @Standard AND Subject = @Subject";
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance_Slot", BSlot);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher_Name", dr["Teacher_Name"].ToString());
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Standard", dr["Standard"].ToString());
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", dr["Subject"].ToString());
                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        j++;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I usually use : DataRow dr in dt.AsEnumerable()

Comment: Mind to share the right coding to do the steps? Thanks.

Comment: Would you mind telling us the error you are getting.

Comment: Why are you doing j++ inside the for loop when it get incremented automatically?  You are doing j++ in three different places in the code.

Comment: j++ because want to skip and continue next. Any better suggestion? and i need to loop it from 1 until 9 again and again.

Comment: The don't put the increment in the for : for (int j = 1; j <= 9;)

Comment: After amended to for (int j = 1; j <= 9) , it stated error ; expected.

Comment: My code has the semicolon, yours doesn't.  I learned this syntax from the C Language book written by K & R (inventors of unix) from 1972 and it still works.

Comment: Yeah...added ; removed another error.

Got two more errors:
The name 'Balance_Slot' does not exist in the current context.
another error is
The name 'j' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Why are you changing j before the for loop.

Comment: u mean this if (Balance_Slot.IsNullOrEmpty()) { j++; } ?? 
Sorry wrong... I actually want to skip for next row data instead of j++. How to ya? Thanks.

Comment: You need to define j before it is used : int j = 0;.  So I would change the for to a While(j < 9).  Then increment j as needed in the code.

Comment: if (Balance_Slot.IsNullOrEmpty()) { j++; } 

How to change to skip for next row data instead of j++ ?

Comment: If change to While (j < 9), got another error the name 'While' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do with 'j'.  The code posted doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: I want to loop it from Group_Odd_1 until Group_Odd_9 and repeat again. So I used J to identity 1 until 9.

Comment: When Balance_Slot is empty there is no reason to do j++.

Comment: Yes...correct you are right... so i coded it wrongly. But how to code it to skip and continue with next datarow?

Comment: Why do you need to repeat? Still don't understand.

Comment: I want to grab the teacher_name and insert into 9 different groups. But each groups cannot consist of same teacher and cannot same Standard(class). each subject has limited balance_slot. So repeat actually is to repeat twice will do just to recheck as it could be start from j = 5 at the middle and it doesn't check j = 1 until j = 4.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question and the information you included seems vague. Also, as you said, you encountered errors (you should include them in your question).

To start, let me correct some errors in your query:

```
cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM group_odd_" + j + " WHERE (Teacher_Name == @Teacher_Name OR Standard == @Standard OR Subject == @Subject)";
```

In this line, you are using two `=` sign in your `WHERE` clause. This is incorrect syntax in sql, you should use only one:

```
cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM group_odd_" + j + " WHERE (Teacher_Name = @Teacher_Name OR Standard = @Standard OR Subject = @Subject)";
```

If this not solve your error, please include the error you get. As for your requirement, it would be good if you add sample data and your expected results.

**UPDATE:** (explaining errors)

> 1. The name 'Balance_Slot' does not exist in the current context.

Can you please confirm that `Balance_Slot` column exists in `GroupOdd` table?

```
//this line here
cmd2.CommandText = "Update GroupOdd set Balance_Slot = Balance_Slot - 1 WHERE Teacher_Name = @Teacher_Name AND Standard = @Standard AND Subject = @Subject";
```

> 2. The name 'j' does not exist in the current context.

In this code block:

```
        if (Balance_Slot.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            j++; //here
        }
```

you are incrementing `j` but `j` is not accessible at this level because you have declared `j` inside your `for-loop`:

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
{
    ....
}
```

Hence, this will throw an error.

And as a tip, use `continue` to skip the current loop iteration and proceed to the next. This will work for both `for` and `foreach` loop. I do not understand if this is what you really want (to skip to the next iteration, i.e `j=0` and continue to `j=1`). But your code will not do this. Instead, if current `j=0`, it will continue to `j=2`, not `j=1` since you already incremented it once:

```
....
else
{
    j++;
}
```

Comment: I just added sample data as above. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the changes i suggested regarding `==` to `=` ? (check line after `DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();`)

Comment: amended, but haven't able to run because still got error.

Comment: Got two more errors: The name 'Balance_Slot' does not exist in the current context. another error is The name 'j' does not exist in the current context.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Code should look something like this

```
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Teacher_Name, Standard, Subject, Balance_Slot FROM GroupOdd order by sum_weekly_slot desc";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            int BalanceSlot = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Balance_Slot"].ToString());

            if (BalanceSlot > 0)
            {

                for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
                {
                    //bool TeacherNameExist = true;
                    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
                    cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM group_odd_" + j + " WHERE (Teacher_Name = @Teacher_Name OR Standard = @Standard OR Subject = @Subject)";
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher_Name", dr["Teacher_Name"].ToString());
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Standard", dr["Standard"].ToString());
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", dr["Subject"].ToString());
                    SQLiteDataAdapter da2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd2);
                    da2.Fill(dt2);
                    if (dt2.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                         int BSlot = BalanceSlot - 1;
                        cmd2.CommandText = "Update GroupOdd set Balance_Slot = @Balance_Slot WHERE Teacher_Name = @Teacher_Name AND Standard = @Standard AND Subject = @Subject";
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Balance_Slot", BSlot);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher_Name", dr["Teacher_Name"].ToString());
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Standard", dr["Standard"].ToString());
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", dr["Subject"].ToString());
                        int rowsModified = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if(rowsModified == 0)
                        {
                           //cmd2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO group_odd_" + j + " (Teacher_Name, Standard, Subject) VALUES (@Teacher_Name, @Standard, @Subject)";
                           cmd2.CommandText = "Update group_odd_" + j + " SET Teacher_Name = @Teacher_Name, Standard = @Standard, Subject = @Subject";
                           cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Teacher_Name", dr["Teacher_Name"].ToString());
                           cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Standard", dr["Standard"].ToString());
                           cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Subject", dr["Subject"].ToString());
                           int rowsModified = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
```

Comment: Got two error: 
dr does not exist in the current context ( in the beginning part)
and Balance_Slot does not exist in the current context.

Thanks.

Comment: Btw, ur codes seems doesn't perform what i want. because ur codes wrote if (dt.Rows.Count == 0), do insert and update? which is not right.

Comment: The code you posted is also missing Balance_Slot.  If my code is wrong fix it.  I'm not a mind reader and don't know your requirements.  Just did the best I could with your non-working code.

Comment: Yeah...typo Balance_Slot. Btw, I re-upload just amended code as attached. It is without error, but didn't update any value on Group_Odd_1 until Group_Odd_9 datatable. after run, got an error contextswitchdeadlock.

Btw, thank you very much for your suggestion. hope you don't mind keep helping me.

Comment: I starting to see the issue.  You are trying to find when a row is not in the database and add item.  You do not need to skip.  If you test to see if and rows have change you can then add missing info without skipping.  See modified code.

Comment: I tried the modified code, but Group_Odd_1 until Group_Odd_9 didn't get any data updated. 

The actual scenario is... there is 54 set of teacher_name, standard, subject in GroupOdd needs to insert to Group_Odd_1 until Group_Odd_9, but each group of Group_Odd_ cannot be same teacher and also cannot same standard and consist of 6 different teacher_name with 6 different standard and subjects. 

Thanks for your help.